# What Language Is an HTTP Header Written In?

Tags: http, httprequest

The following is an HTTP header. What language or syntax is this code written in?

```
HTTP/2.0 200 OK
Content-type: text/html
Set-Cookie: yummy_cookie=choco
Set-Cookie: tasty_cookie=strawberry
```

It's not JavaScript or PHP. Here is another example taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

```
GET /sample_page.html HTTP/2.0
Host: www.example.org
Cookie: yummy_cookie=choco; tasty_cookie=strawberry
```

Answer (score 0):

They are part of the de-facto standard definition of HTTP, codified in a so-called RFC, or Request For Comments. RFCs are a collection of de-facto standards concerning the foundations of what people know as The Internet.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-31:

> ### 4.2 Message Headers
>
> HTTP header fields, which include general-header (section 4.5),
> request-header (section 5.3), response-header (section 6.2), and
> entity-header (section 7.1) fields, follow the same generic format as
> that given in Section 3.1 of RFC 822 [9]. Each header field consists
> of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value. Field names
> are case-insensitive. The field value MAY be preceded by any amount
> of LWS, though a single SP is preferred. Header fields can be
> extended over multiple lines by preceding each extra line with at
> least one SP or HT. Applications ought to follow "common form", where
> one is known or indicated, when generating HTTP constructs, since
> there might exist some implementations that fail to accept anything
> beyond the common forms.
>
> ```
> message-header = field-name ":" [ field-value ]
> field-name     = token
> field-value    = *( field-content | LWS )
> field-content  = <the OCTETs making up the field-value
>                  and consisting of either *TEXT or combinations
>                  of token, separators, and quoted-string>
> ```

Comment: So the language used to describe HTTP headers and cookies is called RFC?

Comment: @RickHelston: They are part of the protocol named "HTTP". They are not a language in itself, but merely a "sub-language" of HTTP. The definition of HTTP is codified as an RFC.